# program not updating background color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, buffer

I am quite new to java and I apologize if this is a silly question. Below is my code.

```
private void draw(){
    //this is where the background is going to be made
    //paddles gonna be made here as well plus the score and the ball
    //will dispose here

    BufferStrategy Buffer = this.getBufferStrategy();

    if(Buffer==null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics graphics = Buffer.getDrawGraphics();

    //drawing the background
    drawbg(graphics);

    //disposing everything. disposing means to actually show on the screen
    graphics.dispose();
    Buffer.show();
    }


private void drawbg(Graphics graphics){
    //black bg
    graphics.setColor(Color.red);
    graphics.fillRect(0,0,W,H); //fills the whole screen
```

When I run this code, my Jframe application still only has a white background but shouldn't it have a red background since I set the color and then dispose ? Am I missing some code in the question ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) It's far too soon to be trying to use a `BufferStrategy`. First become proficient in creating standard GUIs.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that it should be `Color.RED`. With all caps. I can't comment because it won't let me, but try that out. Make sure that your coordinates do actually fill the whole screen up, I know that JFrame and JPanel can sometimes be weird with that kind of stuff.

Comment: *"I know that JFrame and JPanel can sometimes be weird with that kind of stuff."* This sentence is a hint as to why you are restricted from giving answers. Don't try to game the system.

Comment: *"at least try to help the person"* I [posted a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419190/program-not-updating-background-color/64420396?noredirect=1#comment113994127_64419190) for the OP to add a [mre] & added the [Swing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64419190/revisions) to draw attention to the people most able to help. Still waiting for them to take action on the suggestion.. If people asking questions ignore suggestions, they are unlikely to get help.